# Moving multiple files in a single directory based on filename to multiple folders

Tags: batch-file

First of all thank you in advance for the assistance. What I was trying to do is this:

1) I have a folder containing files with names:

```
122098_482056_1453458.xls
122098_482057_1453459.jpg
122098_482057_1453460.xls
122098_482056_1453457.jpg
```

2) I want to move these files to folders that I have created with names:

```
PO_90_122118_0_US
PO_90_122122_0_US
PO_90_122098_0_US
```

Note: The 3rd part of the folder's name matches with first part of the name of the files.

I have tried the following script which resulted in an error respectively has done nothing.

I have used `delims=_` as my file names are delimited by the character `_`.
`tokens=1` is used so that the first part of the file name is used.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=D:\2009\2nd step batch - Copy"
SET "destdir=D:\2009\1st step batch"
FOR /f "delims=_" %%I IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=(" %%s IN ("%%~I") DO (
  IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%s*" ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%s*" "%destdir%\%%I\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This batch file does not output any line which means there is no file found to move and I don't know why.

What is wrong in batch code to move all `122098_*` files to folder `PO_90_122118_0_US`?

Comment: You need to try it on your own as StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! When you are stuck come back here, share your code and precisely describe the issue you are facing! Read at least the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to use this site! Consult also the following help topics: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: i apologize for this. i have tried out a code but had errors pasting it before until i found the ctrl+k function. i have included my try on the code above.

Comment: Why are you using `delims=(` although there are no `(` in the file names? There is no `tokens` option for the first (outer) `for /F` loop, so it defaults to `tokens=1`, which is not what you want I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your batch code rewritten for this task.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "SourceDir=D:\2009\2nd step batch - Copy"
SET "DestDir=D:\2009\1st step batch"
FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=_" %%A IN ('DIR /AD /B "%DestDir%\*" 2^>nul') DO (
    IF EXIST "%SourceDir%\%%C_*" MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%C_*" "%DestDir%\%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D\"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

You might insert **ECHO** left to **MOVE** for testing the batch file before really moving the files in a second run without **ECHO**.

For each subdirectory found in destination directory the directory name is split up into 4 tokens using underscore as delimiter.

1. `PO` is assigned to loop variable `A` as defined on **FOR** command line.
2. `90` is assigned to next loop variable in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is `B`.
3. `122098` or the other numbers of real interest are assigned to loop variable `C`.
4. And last everything after third underscore in subdirectory name is assigned to loop variable `D` without further splitting up.

The **IF** condition checks if there is any file starting with the number from subdirectory name assigned to loop variable `C` and an underscore. The appropriate files are moved if this condition is true.

It is important to specify as destination directory all 4 parts of the subdirectory name, i.e. the complete name of the current subdirectory.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

`2^>nul` redirects the confusing error message output by command **DIR** to handle **STDERR** in case of no subdirectory found to the device **NUL** to suppress it. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted as redirection operator on execution of command **DIR** and not as misplaced redirection operator for command **FOR**. See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).